# Ler string json em php

Tags: php, json, foreach

Preciso ler o arquivo abaixo:

```
string '{"object":"list","hasMore":true,"limit":10,"offset":0,"data":[{"city":{"object":"city","id":15873,"ibgeCode":"3550308","name":"SÃ£o Paulo","districtCode":"00","district":"SÃ£o Paulo","state":"SP"}},{"city":{"object":"city","id":15718,"ibgeCode":"5200050","name":"Abadia de GoiÃ¡s","districtCode":"05","district":"Abadia de GoiÃ¡s","state":"GO"}},{"city":{"object":"city","id":9853,"ibgeCode":"3100104","name":"Abadia dos Dourados","districtCode":"05","district":"Abadia dos Dourados","state":"MG"}},{"city":{"obj'... (length=1415)
```

Já tentei todos os exemplos que encontrei, mas nenhum me ajudou. O último que testei foi:

```
foreach($obj->data->city as $sthudent_o)
{
    echo $sthudent_o;
    echo $sthudent_o->id. " name is ".$sthudent_o->name[0];
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Se alguém puder me ajuda, agradeço!

Comment: Você usou `json_deconde()` antes? mostre como criou `$obj`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente você tem que transformar a string em um objeto usando o `json_decode( $string )` do PHP.

E agora, no seu código, o item do objeto a ser percorrido é o `data` e não o city.

Você também pode usar o `print_r` para imprimir a estrutura do objeto e ter uma melhor visão de como manipula-lo.

```
$obj = json_decode( $json );

//print_r( $obj );

foreach( $obj->data as $data ) {

    //print_r( $data );

    $dados = $data->city;

    echo 'ID: ' . $dados->id;
    echo '<br>Nome: ' . $dados->name;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Utilize `json_decode()` para transforma a string em um array informando o segundo argumento como `true`, depois faça o foreach.

```
<?php


$str = '[{"object":"list","hasMore":true,"limit":10,"offset":0,"data":[{"city":{"object":"city","id":15873,"ibgeCode":"3550308","name":"SÃ£o Paulo","districtCode":"00","district":"SÃ£o Paulo","state":"SP"}},
                                                              {"city":{"object":"city","id":15718,"ibgeCode":"5200050","name":"Abadia de GoiÃ¡s","districtCode":"05","district":"Abadia de GoiÃ¡s","state":"GO"}},
                                                              {"city":{"object":"city","id":9853,"ibgeCode":"3100104","name":"Abadia dos Dourados","districtCode":"05","district":"Abadia dos Dourados","state":"MG"}}
                                                             ]}]';
$json = json_decode($str, true);

foreach($json[0]['data'] as $item){
    echo $item['city']['name'] .'<br>';
}
```

A estrutura do array ficará dessa forma, então achei melhor pegar o retorno como arry do que um objeto.

[Exemplo - ideone](http://ideone.com/2GneLb)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [object] => list
            [hasMore] => 1
            [limit] => 10
            [offset] => 0
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [city] => Array
                                (
                                    [object] => city
                                    [id] => 15873
                                    [ibgeCode] => 3550308
                                    [name] => SÃƒÂ£o Paulo
                                    [districtCode] => 00
                                    [district] => SÃƒÂ£o Paulo
                                    [state] => SP
                                )

                        )
```