# Recuperando valor string JSON

Tags: php, javascript, json

Tenho uma aplicação `PHP` que me retorna uma `string` `Json`:

```
$cep = $_POST['cep'];

$token = '';
$url = 'http://www.cepaberto.com/api/v2/ceps.json?cep=' . $cep;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Token token="' . $token . '"'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
echo $output;
```

Gostaria de saber como faço para pegar o valor da string que é retornada

> `{"altitude":14.3,"bairro":"Santa Inês","cep":"68901487","latitude":"0.0355735","longitude":"-51.070535","logradouro":"Passarela Acelino de Leão","cidade":"Macapá","ddd":96,"ibge":"1600303","estado":"AP"}`

Comment: [Duplicata](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/96887/ler-string-json-em-php)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utilize [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php) para transformar em um `array` ***associativo***, ***exemplo***:

```
<?php

$cep = $_POST['cep'];

$token = '';
$url = 'http://www.cepaberto.com/api/v2/ceps.json?cep=' . $cep;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Token token="' . $token . '"'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);


$array = json_decode($output, true);

echo $array['altitude'];
echo $array['bairro'];
echo $array['cep'];
echo $array['latitude'];
echo $array['longitude'];
echo $array['logradouro'];
echo $array['cidade'];
echo $array['ddd'];
echo $array['ibge'];
echo $array['estado'];
```

e como demonstrado acesse cada chave e imprima o resultado.

<sub>***Referencia:***</sub>

- [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: Muito obrigado! Me ajudou, era exatamente o que precisava!

Answer (score 3):

Em PHP, as funções `json_encode` e `json_decode` servem para se trabalhar com json. No seu caso, o json_decode transformará o texto recebido em um array, facilitando o seu manuseio:

```
$array = json_decode($output);
```